# Pass IP-address to cloud-init metadata

Tags: linux, bash, openstack, kvm, cloud-init

I am searching for a way to pass a ip-address to cloud-init metadata. So when my qcow boots, it does not have to wait for 120 - 180 seconds to boot.

Currently I've created a workaround by adding IP-address information to the userdata part of cloud-init. The con is, it does take some time because cloud-init userdata is only executed after booting the VM.

```
echo -e "
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
\taddress $address
\tnetmask $netmask
\tgateway $gateway
\tdns-nameservers $dnsnameservers
" > /etc/network/interfaces

ifdown eth0; ifup eth0
```

Currently to set the hostname in cloud-init metadata, I've already obtained this part:

```
cat > $config_dir/meta-data <<-EOF
instance-id: $uuid
hostname: $hostname
local-hostname: $hostname
EOF
```

But I need something more solid, more concrete because the cloud-init documentation is very vague

**EDIT:** I've seen that it is possible because Openstack can do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible by using the following format:

```
network-interfaces: |
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  iface eth0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (static ip)
    netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (gateway ip, usually ip address of router)
```

You basically write out the configuration you want your interfaces to have as an interfaces file would look as long as you have 'network-interfaces: |'

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: this has to go into the file meta-data, btw. see also [cloud-init.readthedocs.io](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html#datasource-nocloud)